# Missing scope error when adding new scope even though I am using shopify_app gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I have an app which uses the Rails `shopify_app gem (v11.5.0)`, and I want to add a new scope.
I have added the scope to the shopify_app.rb initializer and restarted the server, as well as the browser.
When I access the app via the admin interface, or via the install link, I get a `"Oauth error missing_shopify_permission"` error.

I believe this is supposed to work out of the box with the `shopify_app gem`, i.e. the merchant should be prompted about granting the new scope - am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks,
Louise

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that some of the scopes in the graphql API does not exist c.f. https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/write-publications-and-read-publications-access/m-p/506802 and https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Missed-access-scope-in-settings/m-p/449760